# How to stop the page navigating away with custom message as used in hotmail / outlook.com?

Tags: php, javascript, browser, asp-classic, hotmail

I know how to stop the page navigating away and produce a "Stay on this page" / "Leave the page" message with Javascript. The code I use works fine as below. You can place a custom message in the return statement if you wish.

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit()
    {
        return "";
    }
</script>
```

What I would like is a more customizable message such as the one when you hit the back button with an open message in Hotmail / outlook.com. That isn't a standard browser message it seems to create a nice banner across the page. I design using PHP / Javascript but perhaps this is done using ASP?